# How do I debug a free() error in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, exception, free

I have a Python3 program (https://github.com/HowardALandman/QTD/blob/master/src/qtd.py) that has been running fine under Raspbian Buster or Stretch, EXCEPT that occasionally (maybe once per day of runtime) it throws a "free(): invalid pointer" error. This can't be in any Python code (including the tdc7201 driver, which I also wrote), so it must either be an error in a C/C++ library or perhaps in Python's garbage collection itself.  I've tried a few things with no success:

- Put a `try:except:` block around the core method call, where the program spends most of its CPU time. This doesn't catch it, I assume because SIGABRT is not under Exception.
- Tried debugging by running it under `gbd python3-dbg`. The libraries don't seem to support this. The first error I got was `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi._GPIO'` from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/RPi/GPIO/__init__.py`. (What is the underscore even doing there?) I tried patching that by deleting the '_', which seemed to work, but the next error was `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spidev'`. So it might take a bit of work to get everything in place. As far as I can tell, this is a bug in `python3-dbg` and not in `gdb`.
- I could write a signal handler to catch SIGABRT, but that wouldn't by itself give me a stack trace.

Any ideas of how to proceed? I'm a fairly experienced programmer, but this is as far under the Python hood as I've been. I've seen some people suggest valgrind, but 20-30 times slower when the bug takes a day to manifest might imply it would need to run for 3-4 weeks.

NOTE: You won't be able to run the program without a Texas Instruments TDC7201 chip attached to the Raspberry Pi's SPI port.

Comment: `RPi._GPIO` is a C component that `RPi.GPIO` relies on. Changing the name to `RPi.GPIO` piles more breakage on your existing breakage.

Comment: Yup, I undid that after it failed to fix things. RPi.GPIO and python3-dbg are not compatible, which seems like a bug in one or the other. Also, the free() is not throwing SIGABRT; currently trying to figure out what it DOES throw.

Comment: Looking at (one version of) the source code for `free()`, it calls `malloc_printerr()`, which calls `__libc_message()` with the `do_abort` flag set. So it might just die directly without throwing any signal at all.